# Gson handling List Item Pairs of type <String, Object>

Tags: json, gson

I'm reading in a json string the is similar to this...

```
{"flags":{"0":null,"2166136261":null}}
```

I have no idea on how to handle the class representation of this? This is a smaller part of a complex response that I'm slowing trying to class out to make reading and writing from gson simpler.

I just can't figure out how to represent a list item pairs of  in the class file. This seems like something simple I just can't figure it out at the moment. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use code below**

```
class Flag {
    Map<Object, Object> flags;

    public Map<Object, Object> getMap() {
        return flags;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<Object, Object> flags) {
        this.flags = flags;
    }

}
```

**Main class**

```
Flag flag = new Flag();
Map<Object, Object> flags = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
flags.put("0", "test0");
flags.put("1", "test1");
flag.setMap(flags);
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(flag));
```

**Output**

```
{"flags":{"1":"test1","0":"test0"}}
```

This will create json string you want.